# React Native AR library

Tags: augmented-reality, react-native-ios

I am currently developing a React Native mobile application and I want to render on my screen, while using the mobile device camera, some elements of Augmented Reality.

I have tried to use the THREE.js library along with the ExpoGraphics library but unfortunately I cannot test it as I have an iphone 6 and from what I have seen the minimum hardware requirements are met in iphone 6s or later.

Does anyone have any idea how can I render some AR components on my iphone 6 using React Native implementation or how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Wikitude, which I myself have done. Or, you could probably use vuforia if edited the xcode project directly or perhaps build a bridge layer? Not sure the min device setting for Viro React, probably iphone 6s, i'd assume since that's the min for ARKit